# Basic Expression Language Within iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, parsing

I am looking to create a basic expression language that I can leverage within an iOS application.  I will be pulling these values in from a file at runtime.  In the past I have just leveraged regular expressions for this, but it has its own limitations (as I basically just have two operands and an operator).  I want to have a bit more robust support for expressions like the following:

Some examples:

```
valueA != valueB
(valueA == valueB) && (valueC != valueD)
valueA >= valueB
```

Basically, I would want to provide a dictionary to this expression evaluator and have it pull the values for the variables from that dictionary.

Any thoughts on an efficient way to get this done?  I've done about 5 minutes of research this morning on CoreParse and ParseKit, but I am new to both (and parser generators as a whole).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `NSPredicate`, for example:

```
NSString *expr = @"($valueA == $valueB) && ($valueC != $valueD)";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:expr];
NSDictionary *vars = @{@"valueA": @7, @"valueB" : @7, @"valueC": @3, @"valueD": @4};
BOOL result = [predicate evaluateWithObject:nil substitutionVariables:vars];
```

Note that all variables have to start with a `$` in the predicate string.